# Equivalent of joda LocalTime getMillisOfDay() in noda

Tags: c#, jodatime, nodatime

I am porting some code from Java to .NET and looking for a noda-time equivalent of the `getMillisOfDay()` joda-time method of the LocalTime object.

Is there an equivalent one or must I code my own?

Comment: Not familiar with noda-time, is millisOfDay the number of milliseconds since midnight of a given DateTime?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: ...Why are you using `LocalTime`?  The need for this type is usually pretty rare, compared to absolute stamps (`Instant` or `DateTime`) .  Especially since midnight does not exist during some DST switches.

Comment: This particular app uses LocalDate/Time throughout since all datetimes are stored in UTC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Noda Time 1.x, use the [`LocalTime.TickOfDay`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/P_NodaTime_LocalTime_TickOfDay.htm) property, and then just divide it by `NodaConstants.TicksPerMillisecond` to get milliseconds:

```
LocalTime localTime = ...;
long millis = localTime.TickOfDay / NodaConstants.TicksPerMillisecond;
```

Comment: Thanks - works fine; although for the original question I think it's TicksPerMillisecond.

Answer (score 0):

Closest you can get to the *number of milliseconds since midnight* with out-of-the-box .Net functionality:

```
dateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds
```

e.g.

```
double millisOfDay = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
```

`TimeOfDay` returns the `TimeSpan` since midnight (time of day) and `TotalMilliseconds` returns (the name might have given it away) the total number of milliseconds of that `TimeSpan`.

It's a `double` by the way, so you'll also get fractions of milliseconds. If you need this a lot, an extension method may be helpful:

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
{
    // should of course be in pascal case ;)
    public static int getMillisOfDay(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return (int) dateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
    }
}

int millisOfDay = DateTime.Now.getMillisOfDay();
```

Comment: Note this only works if you're either using UTC, or _ignoring the time zone_ (either with `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, or just treating it as "local" and pretending the time zone doesn't exist), since otherwise this will (potentially) return the wrong value twice a year: `DateTime`, contrary to expectations, is DST/time zone ignorant for all methods and results (except for `ToUniveralTime()`/`ToLocalTime()`.  The `TimeSpan` will be an hour short/long on DST days (assuming you're on an hour-different DST zone, and not something else).