# How to convert local time zone to joda time zone in c#

Tags: asp.net

For example : my local time zone is `(UTC +05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi` and its joda time zone is `Asia/kolkata`
I want to get **Joda TimeZone**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of joda LocalTime getMillisOfDay() in noda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590559/equivalent-of-joda-localtime-getmillisofday-in-noda)

Comment: Thanks Alaeddine,
how can i get joda timezone name using getMillisOfDay() ?